# Activities running issue. Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

BI have a class B in Android that extends the main class(A). When I click on a button the first screen is closed(or put on stop), and the second screen opens (B). My problem is that when that second screen opens, it will automatically start the onCreate of class A again(because it extends it, I know this because if I delete the extends part everything is fine, but I need that extend for some facilities of class A). I can't change the activity A to "singleInstance" because it will be bad for some parts of my program. Is it possible to keep class B extending class A, but when I click on that button class A won't start again ?

```
public class A extends ActionBarActivity {
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
}



public class B extends A {}
```

edit: I did like that article said and I created `private A myOtherActivity` and if I did something like `myOtherActivity.method(something); java wouldn t complain. But when I run the app I get

```
26885-26885/asd.them.get.pampam E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: together.them.get.bangbang, PID: 26885
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at pampam.them.get.pampam.PickScreen$1.onClick(B.java:43)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19339)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The method that I was calling from activity A was `public String returnString(){
        return "This is working";
    }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need 3 classes to do what you want.

```
public abstract class A extends ActionBarActivity{}
public class B extends A {}
public class C extends A {}
```

Comment: I can't make class A abstract :D .. I get a lot of error if I do, which I don't really know how to correct

Comment: Move the instance-logic that gives you a lot of errors into class B.  Class "B" becomes what you're old "Class A" was.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other class an abstract class c or you can see according to your if you want to use an interface. implement the interface or extend the abstract class according to your requirement. And in case of activity you have to extend the class B to base class ACTIVITY only.

Comment: An abstract class will kill my activity instantly .. In my main class I'm connecting a bluetooth and opening a data connection. I have a method which sends data in class A. That is the method that I'm trying to import in class B. The only way to do that is to extend the class(there are too many things to be imported otherwise). I want to write something in my onCreate method of class B that won't start the activity in class A again.

Comment: Tried that, but I have non-static fields in that method

Comment: I would advise against the " I want to write something in my onCreate method of class B that won't start the activity in class A again" approach.

Comment: If you extend class A to B then there is no way to stop calling oncreate of activity A reason is always base class is initialized first ....I have found a blog I don't know if it will work  http://learn-it-stuff.blogspot.in/2011/12/calling-method-from-one-android-java.html

Comment: @thestrongenough I tried that article but no luck. I edited my post so you can see what I'm getting now.